# Google Maps Api search json results

Tags: api, search, google-maps

What do I need to use to get a search listing
using the google maps API?

I can get one address
or lat/long but I want to search for say "bars 84070"
and get a list of addresses and lat/long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the list of results you get back from your [search api query](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#SearchControlCallbacks):

```
App.prototype.onSearchComplete = function (sc, searcher) {

    for (var i = 0; i < searcher.results.length; i++)
    {
        var resultLat = searcher.results[i].lat;
        var resultLng = searcher.results[i].lng;
        var point = new GLatLng(resultLat,resultLng);
        var html = results[i].html;

        // do something with the results
    }
}
```

**Update**:

According to the *Search* object [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_class_GSearch) if you specify that you want a "large" (google.search.Search.LARGE_RESULTSET) number of results, you will typically get 8 results.

I suggest if you want more local results for an are, you make multiple local search requests for a range of center points and then filter out the duplicates.

Comment: nice, how can I control the number of results? Do you know? I want way more.